# C++ Parse command line parameters and bool

Tags: c++, parsing, command-line, boolean

So, I'm trying to add something that allows me to use argv to allow three command line inputs.

such that:

```
./program input.dat (string input)
```

so that (I assume) `argv[0] = input.dat` and `argv[1] = string input`, `argue[2] = file output`

...I'm not sure if I'm explaining it right, but this is my best effort.
what I want to do is have a command line input that allows me to have like, if it says "encrypt" it makes a bool true, and if I type "decrypt" it sets that bool to false.

Comment: `argv[0]` is always the name of the program. The arguments start at `argv[1]`.

Comment: What language are you using? Doesn't it have an argument parsing library, like `getopt`?

Comment: yeah, sorry, thats what i meant. Im using C++, sorry I've kind of messed up this questions! I'm fairly new to programming (this is the end of my second semester)

Comment: can you put an actual command line example? or is that "(string input)" the actual string that you are passing to the program ?

Comment: thats just a placeholder, what I'm really trying to do is have it so I type in 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'

Comment: Then what is `file output`? There's no placeholder for that, but you mention it in `argv`.

Comment: wow. okay. So Im used to using argv[1] for file input, and argv[2] for outputting to a .dat file. Im trying to figure out how to type another argument parameter that is connected to a bool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool encrypt;
std::string action(argv[2]);
if (action == "encrypt") {
    encrypt = true;
} else if (action == "decrypt") {
    encrypt = false;
} else {
    // Report invalid argument
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're describing:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        // print usage here and return, since that's what you need.
    }

    const char* filename = argv[1];

    if (!strcmp(argv[2], "encrypt")) {
        // encrypt!
    }
    else if (!strcmp(argv[2], "decrypt")) {
        // decrypt!
    }
    else {
        // error!
    }
}
```

Or alternatively with strings:

```
std::string filename = argv[1];
std::string mode = argv[2];
if (mode == "encrypt") { 
    // etc.
}
```

You can have lots of args, There's nothing to stop you from calling:

```
./program hi everybody this is a little excessive but just an example
```

At which point, you'd get called with `argc == 12` and, e.g., `argv[5]` pointing to `"a"``.